# Hide Unhide Specific Sheets Slow

Tags: excel, vba

I always see a lot of good info here and I'm usually able to create codes that work, but rarely are they efficient. I have about 25 sheets that can be split into 4 different groups, instead of seeing all 25 tabs at bottom I want to see only 1 group at a time plus a home page

```
Sub Unhide_Group1()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(ws.Name, "Group1") > 0 Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        
        ElseIf InStr(ws.Name, "Group2") > 0 Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
       
        ElseIf InStr(ws.Name, "Group3") > 0 Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden

        ElseIf InStr(ws.Name, "Group4") > 0 Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            
        End If
    Next ws

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

I have 4 different versions of the above code to hide tabs depending on tab names, 1 for each group. The current method does a big flash and stutters a little bit, is there a better way to do the above? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to have multiple subs for that - just create one routine that receives a parameter that tells which group to show.

To avoid screen flickering, disable screen update while the code runs.

```
Sub Unhide_Group(group As Integer)

    Const HomeSheetName = "Sheet1"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> HomeSheetName Then
            ws.Visible = IIf(InStr(ws.Name, "Group" & group) > 0, xlSheetVisible, xlSheetHidden)
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets(HomeSheetName).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Update**
As you can't assign a Sub to a button if it has parameters, you can create 4 simple Subs that contain just a call to the unhide routine:

```
Sub ButtonGroup1_Click()
    Unhide_Group 1
End Sub
```

It's good practice anyhow to separate event handler and program logic.

If you don't like that, you can create one event routine that is called from all buttons and that figure out which group to show using the `Application.Caller` property.

Comment: I've adjusted for use and works so much better, however I had to remove "group as integer" otherwise it wasn't showing up in my Macros list so I can assign to button, I guess I'm missing something? Much much appreciated.

Comment: You're right, it's not possible to use a sub with parameters as an event handler. Updated my answer

Comment: Ahh, is it possible to put multiple name conditions in an InStr function? For example "Group" and "Stats", so I can future proof?

Comment: No, but you  can use 2 separate Instr-functions, or have a look at the `like` operator

Comment: I think I got it, `ws.Visible = IIf(InStr(ws.Name, "Group") Or InStr(ws.Name, "Stats") > 0, xlSheetVisible, xlSheetHidden)` seems to do the trick. Thank you very very much for the prompt help.